# Vue.js make use of global list

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to make use of a `list` in my

new Vue , but it's not working. When I try this with a component it works this is my idea:

```
  Vue.component('employees', {
            template: '#employees',
            props:['list'],
            created() {
                this.list = JSON.parse(this.list);
            }
        });

        <employees list="{{ $employees }}"></employees>
```

That ^ is working.
In my component I show in a foreach all employees in a list. 
But how can I use list within `new Vue` so I can acces it from every component. I know you can for example sync a var like this: `:selectedrole.sync="role"` But how would this work with a list? Something like this? `:list="{{ $employees }}".sync="employees"` ?

And then in my `new Vue`this?:

```
 new Vue({
            el: 'body',
            data:{
                list: '',
                created() {
                    this.list = JSON.parse(this.list);
                }
            }
        });
```

I'm using Laravel and `$employees` is just an employees object.

I hope I've explained it well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should only bind plain text or variable to Component props. Mustache expression not works there.

ie.

```
<myComponent a="plain text" :b="obj"></myComponent>
new Vue({
  data: {obj: {foo: 'bar'}}
  components: {myComponent: myComponent}
})
```

[Props](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Props)